# Find the parametrization of the intersection of two surfaces

Tags: calculus, 3d

I need to find the parametrization of the intersection for the two surfaces defined by these equations:

$x^2+y^2=25$ and $z^2+y^2=25$

I'm not quite sure how to do it. What is the best way?

Comment: Think pythagorean theorem and think $5sint$ and $5cost$ for both of them

Comment: The punchline is that whenever $x^2+y^2=25$ and $z^2+y^2=25$ are true simultaneously then $x=z$ or $x=-z$.  If you can parametrize $x^2+y^2=25$, then you can parametrize this larger problem.

Comment: Orthogonal intersection of cylinders is a famous problem and you can find a lot of literature on the internet including parametrization, surface area, volume etc. In this link, you can see some nice diagrams that help visualize things better. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Solutions/CalcIII/SurfaceArea/Prob5.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see the union of two circles $x=z, x^2+y^2=25$ and $x=-z, x^2+y^2=25$

A good parametrization is for instance for the first circle, $x= 5 \cos(u), y=5 \sin(u), z= 5 \cos(u)$ and $x= 5 \cos(u), y=5 \sin(u), z= -5 \cos(u)$ for the second.

Comment: I would hesitate to call these objects circles.  They are ellipses.  Their shadows (*projections onto $x$-$y$ planes or $z$-$y$ planes*) are circles, but the shapes themselves do not satisfy that their distance at all points to the center (*in this case the origin*) is constant.  $(5,0,5)$ is further from the center than $(0,5,0)$ is.

Comment: Yes indeed, "circle" is a mistake !